# NullPointerException with custom font from assets

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-assets

I'm trying to use custom font in my application, but i got that exception when when run the app:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setTypeface(android.graphics.Typeface)' on a null object reference
```

I have a working font and it's in the right path and that's my code:

```
private TextView tv;
private Typeface tf;

    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.wlcText);
    tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "en_font.ttf");
    tv.setTypeface(tf);
```

That's my XML:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/mainView"
    android:background="@color/semi_transparent_black"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/wlcText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:text="Test"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Could you post `onCreate()` code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`tv` is `null`. For whatever reason (e.g., failure to call `setContentView()`), you do not have a widget in the activity that can be found via `R.id.wlcText`.

Comment: I edited the question and showed the xml, what wrong in it please?

Comment: @commons The `tf` is null not `tv`.

Comment: @Codester `tv` is `null`. He tries to call setTypeface method on a null object.

Comment: @issathink By looking in his xml, how can his `tv` be a null ?

Comment: @issathinkSo how to fix that?!  am new to Android and don't know actually

Comment: He could possibly didn't call `setContentView()` or call it after `findViewById()`

Comment: @Mohamed Did you call `setContentView()`, ?

Comment: @Mohamed: Make sure that your code that you have above is being called *after* you inflate this layout, and that your `findViewById()` call matches how you are inflating the layout. As it stands, your Java code shown above would only work if your layout is being inflated via `setContentView()`, and then only if your `findViewById()` call is after the `setContentView()` call. If you are trying to use this layout in other ways (e.g., as the content of a fragment), your code to retrieve the widget would need to change.

Comment: @Mohamed: Beyond that, you can try cleaning your project (e.g., Project > Clean from the main menu in Eclipse, Build > Clean Project from the main menu in Android Studio) and see if that helps. Occasionally, the `R` class gets out of sync with the rest of the project.

Comment: @CommonsWare it could be more interesting and more visible if you put these explanations in your response.

Comment: Yeah i got it, i made custom font for `TextView` in dialog and i set the custom font code in the `onCreate()` bur i must set it in the `dialog` method, so i must do that `tv = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.wlcText);` now it's works!