# Custom fonts in Android do not work

Tags: android, android-layout

I have written this code:

```
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "lato.woff2");
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
tv.setTypeface(tf);
```

But it crashes because:

```
"Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Font asset not found lato.woff2"
```

I put the font file, lato.woff2, in these folders:

```
src/main/assets/font/
src/main/assets/
```

So, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: android support only .ttf file for fonts family and put your .ttf file in assets folder only

Comment: Andoid supports only TTF (or) OTF format

Comment: @NiteshPareek Done, but now I get this error: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setTypeface(android.graphics.Typeface)' on a null object reference

Comment: check this [LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30549351/nullpointerexception-with-custom-font-from-assets) its solve your error

Comment: @NiteshPareek Thanks but I have just notices that the textview is in another .xml layout. How can I do ?

Answer (score 0):

`getAssets()` from `getApplicationContext()`.

```
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getApplicationContext().getAssets(), "lato.woff2");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add your font file under assests path :

```
 Typeface mTypeface == Typeface.createFromAsset(getApplicationContext().getAssets(), "lato.woff2");
```

if you add your font under assests/fonts/ folder path :

```
Typeface mTypeface == Typeface.createFromAsset(getApplicationContext().getAssets(), "fonts/lato.woff2");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are able to not to reinvent the wheel, if you would use [Calligraphy](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy) library. All you need to do is override onCreate() method in your application class like this:

```
CalligraphyConfig.initDefault(new CalligraphyConfig.Builder()
                            .setDefaultFontPath("fonts/Roboto-RobotoRegular.ttf")
                            .setFontAttrId(R.attr.fontPath)
                            .build()
```

And then inject into context (it will work for whole app, if you'll declare it in the BaseActivity of your app):

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
    super.attachBaseContext(CalligraphyContextWrapper.wrap(newBase));
}
```

Now you can use custom fonts in your UI elements like this:

```
<TextView
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    fontPath="fonts/Roboto-Bold.ttf"/>
```

Don't forget to specify application class in your manifest. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you have the tff files in /src/main/assets/fonts you can also create a custom TextView by overriding the constructor:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class OpenSansTextView extends TextView {
    public OpenSansTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet){
        super(context, attributeSet);
        this.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf"));
    }
}
```

and then in your xml layout use:

```
 <YOUR-PACKAGE-NAME.OpenSansTextView
            android:id="@+id/some_id"
            android:text="@string/my_string"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
```